# Google Price Calculator API (GCP)

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

I am looking to build simple billing app for cloud resources using google price calculator https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

Does google provide any API's for interacting with google price calculator?

I tried but couldn't find any!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Cloud Billing Catalog API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api), according to the official documentation:

- Get a list of all public SKUs within a service including:

  - Human readable description of the SKU.
  - Public pricing of the SKU.
  - Regions where the SKU is available for purchase.
  - Categorization data about the SKU.

An example:

Request:

```
GET https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/SERVICE_ID/skus?key=API_KEY
```

Where `SERVICE_ID` is the identifier of the parent service.

Response:

```js
{
  "skus": [
    {
        "name": "[SKU_NAME]",
        "skuId": "[SKU_ID]",
        "description": "[SKU_DESCRIPTION]",
        "category": {
            "serviceDisplayName": "[SVC_DISPLAY_NAME]",
            "resourceFamily": "[FAMILY]",
            "resourceGroup": "[GROUP]",
            "usageType": "[USAGE]",
        },
        "serviceRegions": [
          "[REGION]"
        ],
        "pricingInfo": [
          {
              "effectiveTime": "[TIME]",
              "summary": "[SUMMARY]",
              "pricingExpression": {
                  "usageUnit": "[UNIT]",
                  "usageUnitDescription": "[UNIT_DESCRIPTION]",
                  "displayQuantity": [DISPLAY_QUANTITY],
                  "tieredRates": [
                    {
                        "startUsageAmount": [START_AMOUNT],
                        "unitPrice": {
                            "currencyCode": "[CURRENCY_CODE]",
                            "units": [UNITS],
                            "nanos": [NANOS],
                        },
                    }
                  ],
              },
              "aggregationInfo": {
                  "aggregationLevel": enum("[AGGREGATION_LEVEL]"),
                  "aggregationInterval": enum("[AGGREGATION_INTERVAL]"),
                  "aggregationCount": [AGGREGATION_COUNT],
              },
              "currencyConversionRate": [CONVERSION_RATE],
          }
        ],
        "serviceProviderName": "[SERVICE_PROVIDER]",
    }
  ]
}
```

According to your question, you would want to use these response objects:

- `[UNIT]` is the short hand for the unit of usage in which the pricing is specified. For example, usageUnit of `GiBy` means that usage is specified in "Gibibytes".
- `[DISPLAY_QUANTITY]` is the recommended quantity of units for displaying pricing info. When displaying pricing info, it is recommended to display: `(unitPrice * displayQuantity) per displayQuantity usageUnit`. This field does not affect the pricing formula and is for display purposes only. For example, if the `unitPrice` is "0.0001 USD", the usageUnit is "GB" and the displayQuantity is "1000", then the recommended way to display the pricing info is "0.10 USD per 1000 GB".